# PHP form won't validate after I linked it with my Localhost(using MySQL and PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm not sure if I am posting this thread in a right way since I made a mistake in my first post and got few answers which said " This site is for helping people with their code not writing it for them".

Anyways I'm a new coder(not actually, I just use Dreamweaver and edit codes) and I'm facing problems with my form validation(JS, CSS, HTML). When ever I link my form with MySQL, the form will no more validate and just submits the empty fields with NULL.

**Javascript** file

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.0/mootools-yui-compressed.js

**CSS**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B90yvjWksukydVNZZmU0eGtDSnc/edit?usp=sharing

**HTML** file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B90yvjWksukyd2hTRFFvTjBjUUU/edit?usp=sharing

```
<?php require_once('Connections/localhost.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['email'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "test_page.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "form_signin.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT Email, Password FROM users WHERE Email=%s AND Password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">

    <link href="css/contact.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">

<?php

// Set email variables
$email_to = 'ikhlak.shaikh@yahoo.com';
$email_subject = 'Form submission';

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email','password');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
    'firstname' => 'Please enter a Name to proceed.',
    'lastname' => 'Please enter a Name to proceed.',
    'email' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address to continue.',
    'password' => 'Please enter your password to continue.'
);

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();

// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // Sanitise POST array
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

    // Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {       
        // the field has been submitted?
        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

        // check there is information in the field?
        if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

        // validate the email address supplied
        if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
    }

    // basic validation result
    if(count($validation) == 0) {
        // Prepare our content string
        $email_content = 'New Website Comment: ' . "\n\n";

        // simple email content
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n";
        }

        // if validation passed ok then send the email
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content);

        // Update form switch
        $form_complete = TRUE;
    }
}

function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
   return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
</script>
<head>
<body onLoad="MM_preloadImages('images/misc/x.png')">

<!-- Contact Form Designed by James Brand @ dreamweavertutorial.co.uk -->
<!-- Covered under creative commons license - http://dreamweavertutorial.co.uk/permissions/contact-form-permissions.htm -->

<title>Signup|Soleoft</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link href="css/contact.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.0/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" sr="js/form_validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var firstnameError = '<?php echo $error_messages['firstname']; ?>';
        var lastnameError = '<?php echo $error_messages['lastname']; ?>';
        var emailError = '<?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?>';
        var usernameError = '<?php echo $error_messages['username']; ?>';
</script>

</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class='clear'></div>
  <a href="index.php"><img src="images/misc/Capture.PNG" alt="" width="983" height="128" class="container" /></a>
  <div class="container1">
<h1>Create an Account Today.</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h6>Looking for work? <a href="test_page.php">Contact Us</a>. Have an account? Sign In.</h6>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div id="formWrap">
<div id="form">
<?php if($form_complete === FALSE): ?>
<form ACTION="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" name="signin_form" method="POST" id="signin_form"><!-- end .row --><!-- end .row -->

    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Email Address</div>
    <div class="input">
    <input type="text" id="Email" class="detail" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email'])? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>" /><?php if(in_array('email', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- end .input -->
    <div class="context">e.g. John@domain.com</div>
    <!-- end .context -->
  </div><!-- end .row -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Password</div>
    <div class="input">
    <input type="password" id="Password" class="detail" name="password" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['username'])? $_POST['password'] : ''; ?>" />
<?php if(in_array('password', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['password']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- end .input -->
    <div class="context">e.g. Jsmith</div><!-- end .context -->
    </div><!-- end .row --><!-- end .row -->

    <div class="submit">
  <input name="signinbutton" type="submit" class="submit" id="signinbutton" value="Sign up">

  </div><!-- end .submit -->
</form>


  <?php else: ?>
<p style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;">Thank you for your Message!</p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('ourRedirect()', 5000)
function ourRedirect() {
    location.href='loggedin.html'   
}

</div> 
<!-- end #form -->
</div> <!-- end formWrap -->


</body> 
</html><?php
mysql_free_result($RegisterUser);
?><?php
mysql_free_result($RegisterUser);
?>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";

    body {background: #e9e9e9;

    }

#formWrap {
    width: 720px;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:110px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #f1f1f1;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #999;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #999;
    padding: 16px 10px 40px;
}


#form {
    border-top:1px solid #eee
    width:720px;
}


#form .row {
    border-bottom:1px dotted #eee;
    display:block;
    line-height:38px;
    overflow:auto;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:20px;
}


#form .row .label {
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Segoe UI";
    width:180px;
    text-align:right;
    float:left;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}


#form .row .input {
    float: left;
    margin-right:18px;
/*  width:auto; */
    width:285px;

}


    .detail {
        width:260px;
        font-family:"Segoe UI";
        font-size:13px;
        padding: 7px 8px;
        margin:0;
        display:block;
        border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
        background:#FFF;
        border:1px solid;
}


    .detail:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #7bc1f7;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7;
}


#form .row .context {
    color:#eee;
    font-size:11px;
    font-style:italic;
    line-height;14px;
    font-family:"Segoe UI";
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}


#form .submit {
    font-family:"Segoe UI";
    margin-left:100px;
    font-size:18px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #999;
    paddig:10px ;
}

span.error {
    color:#F00;
    display:block;
    font-family:"Segoe UI";
    font-size:12px;
    background-image:url(../images/misc/x.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left 10px;
    padding-left:25px;


}

#formWrap h2 {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    margin-left:25px;
    color:#333  
}

.container .clear, body .clear {width: 720p; float: left; clear: both; margin: 20px 0; padding-top:20px; margin:auto; }

.container1 {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family:"Segoe UI";
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}


h1 {width: 100%; clear: both;  text-align: center; color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2); font-size:36pt; font-weight: 600;}

h6 {width: 100%; clear: both;  text-align: center; color: #000; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2); font-size:9pt; font-weight: bold; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #999;}
```

Comment: hi...welcome to SO....just paste the codes here...no need to show it on link!! :)

Comment: Or use http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io

Comment: You haven't provided any of the code which is supposedly breaking it, how do we know how you are 'linking it with MySQL'?

Comment: Sorry, but umm I really don't know how to add a text area for my codes on SO. I also tried using the help files, but just didn't work I guess

Comment: Indent your code by 1 tab and it will put it into a syntax coloured area.

Comment: @user3157444 type yor code,then select all your code,press ctrl+k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly before you use javascript to validate first learn how to validate in php .
I made for you a basic script which will show you how to validate in php .
This might be a good start for you good luck

```
<html>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
Name: <input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="submit" name = "insert" value = "insert"/>
<BODY > 
<?php
$email = isset($_POST['email'])? trim($_POST['email']):'';
$username = isset($_POST['username'])? trim($_POST['username']):'';
if(empty($_POST['username'])){
 echo "<h4>Enter name </h4>";
 exit();
}
/* PHP form validation: the script checks that the Email field contains a valid email address and the Subject field isn't empty. preg_match performs a regular expression match. It's a very powerful PHP function to validate form fields and other strings - see PHP manual for details. */
 if (!preg_match("/\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/", $email)) {
 echo "<h4>Invalid email address</h4>";
 exit();
 } elseif ($email == "") {
 echo "<h4>Enter email</h4>";

 exit();
 }
?>
```

Comment: But it is like when I unlink my form with MySQL, the javascript validation works well. But when I link it, it just submits.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, just curious why

Comment: But you had to post your codes here so that people can easily Identify your problem

Comment: Yep!! Worked Perfectly

Comment: Okay am glad that it helped you and am requesting please to upvote it . and also if you get any help on this site you should always upvote the answer